# When should I close the ServerSocket opened at app startup?

Tags: android, serversocket

I start a tcp server from my android app when the application starts, which sends some data generated in the app to all connected clients. This server should be available throughout the lifetime of my app.

`ServerSocket` is created in a separated thread, which is spawned in `Application.onCreate()` (I have extended `Application`).

I have a problem in finding an event for closing the `ServerSocket` I opened at app startup. As I have found, there is no guaranteed way to catch application close event.

So how should I close my `ServerSocket`?

One way I see is adding a notification in notification area saying that my server is running, with an option to stop the server. Is this the only way I can achieve this?

Comment: Dose "application close event" mean the application process is killed?

Comment: Basically, it should be any point at which, if user opens my app again, `Application.onCreate()` will get called.

Comment: `So how should I close my ServerSocket?`. That depends on how/where you started it i think. But you did not tell.

Comment: Also you did not tell which problems you encounter at the moment. I suppose that if application finishes your serversocket will be destroyed automatically. And all connections will be gone. What do you want more?